# SetScrollPos: scroll bar moving, but control content not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, user32

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetScrollPos(int hWnd, int nBar);
```

So those are the externs im using to move the scroll position, what im doing, is i get the current position, and add or substract an exact amount of pixels, and the scroll bar on my form moves perfectly how i want it, but the content in the control stays stationary. What is the problem here?

Comment: What control are you scrolling? Also, why isn't the second `hWnd` parameter an `IntPtr`?

Comment: If you are interacting with a Winforms application then there should be no need to use P/Invoke — you should be able to do everything you need using the .NET API provided by the controls.  Could you give a bit more detail about your application?

Comment: it's a custom built UserControl, it has no methods that can control the scroll  to the precision I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct API call! :)

```
    public void ScrollTo(int Position)
    {
        SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, 0x1, Position, true);
        PostMessageA((IntPtr)this.Handle, 0x115, 4 + 0x10000 * Position, 0);
    }
```

before i was just using SetScrollPos, but this combined with PostMessageA works perfectly

Comment: You are breaking the contract for WM_VSCROLL, it never is sent without an SB_ENDSCROLL.  Use the AutoScrollPosition property to control the scrollbar position.

Comment: @nobugs: would you like to elaborate on how i can fix my problem, or post your own answer?